# Render saved HTML string in Firestore in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, jsx

I have some strings stored in Firestore as:

```
item1: {
    content: '<p>Hi</p>'
}
item2: {
    content: '<p>Hi 2</p>'
}
```

When I use the following render function in my React component, it is printing out the paragraph tags (and any other HTML):

```
render() {
  const { items } = this.state

  this.items = items.map(function(item, key) {
    <li key={key}>{item['content']}</li>
  })

  return (
    <ul>
      {this.items}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

How to fix? Any way to do this without dangerouslySetInnerHtml?

Comment: why dont you want to use dangerouslySetInnerHtml?

Comment: It seems dangerous! The item content is user-generated, so does that make the app vulnerable?

Comment: it depends on where your content comes from, I think it is the most common way to insert html to your react code.

Comment: Users are inputting the HTML content in the app, then this component is printing it out somewhere else. I've heard that dangerouslySetInnerHtml should be avoided if possible, so seeing if this would be a case where it would make sense to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using react-html-parser package for this:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser